# Frenar ataques a archivos inexistentes en Cloudflare

Tags: apache, http-post

Últimamente tengo ataques masivos a mi sitio web desde diferentes ip´s a lo largo del día. El asunto es que intentan vulnerar creyendo que estoy usando Wordpress o algún CMS.

A pesar de que no pone en riesgo mi sitio, me imagino que muchas de las peticiones logran burlar Cloudflare e intentan tirarlo.

**¿Cómo puedo bloquear cualquier petición a mi sitio después del /?** Por ejemplo, misitio.com/.env **aunque dichos archivos/rutas no existan?**

**Update**: Estoy usando Aapanel en Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Apache 2.4. No sé usar SSH por tanto no tengo tengo Mod_security instalado ni ningún firewall que no sea Cloudflare.

[image: ejemplo1]

[image: ejemplo2]

Comment: Depende... a ver, esos ataques son normales y frecuentes siempre, y se pueden evitar de muchas formas para que no saturen el servidor. Si usas mod_security puedes establecer reglas para ello, o bien si usas algun firewall tambien, de tal forma que si una IP encuentra x veces una página que no existe la bloquee a ese nivel, pero necesitamos mas contexto de lo que tienes para indicartelo mejor. Tipo de servidor, panel de hosting si usas, sistema operativo, firewall, etc

Comment: @masterguru listo! he actualizado la publicación c:

Comment: No se usar el Cloudflare ese, pero entiendo que ellos tambien bloquean esas cosas en su panel si sabes configurarlo.  Por otra parte, que retornan las peticiones a esos archivos inexistentes?  error 404?  o son interpretadas por tus scripts primero?  Si es esto último entonces debes poner algun filtro en tus scripts para que no consuman demasiados recursos al procesarlas y te cuelguen el servidor. Es decir, que cuando recibas peticiones a tu index, si este sabe reconocer las urls que le llegan, immediatamente les devuelva un error 404 con un die() o exit() para que el script no siga procesando

Comment: @masterguru Al final he optado por simplemente bloquear cualquier petición de los ASN de Amazon AWS, Microsoft y OVH que son de donde provienen la mayoría de los ataques. Muchas gracias de igual forma! 
 [Reglas de Cloudflare](https://i.imgur.com/YLFm73Z.png)

Comment: Ok, veo que en ese aapanel si tienes reglas WAF (deben ser las mismas que las que se usan en el mod_security) pero hay que pagar por ellas. Si no notas nada en tu servidor no le des más importancia a esos ataques, cesan solos si se devuelven errores 404 de página no encontrada normalmente.

Comment: sugerencia, si tu servidor tiene buenos recursos instala fail2ban para bloquear toda ip que intente acceder a url's no activas. yo lo uso y da muy buenos resultados

Comment: @John lo he instalado, pero me confundo en el apartado de "ports" osea que si dejo el puerto 80 solo bloqueará los ataques a dicho puerto? O cual es la forma correcta de que bloquee las peticiones en general despues del /? (Estoy hablando del apartado de Website Protection) Y no sé, tengo 12gb de RAM y 2 cores, es suficiente con eso?

Comment: mas que suficiente con eso, [mira usa esta guia](https://bobcares.com/blog/fail2ban-apache-404/) consentrate en la parte de apache y [esta otra](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) también

Comment: igual te aconsejo instalar el Mod_security para poder monitorizar tu web, también si no se usan los servicios en india y china u otros paises, bloquea los rangos de ip, habilita UFW en ubuntu para eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Lo intentaré por la noche, espero no dejar inservible el vps XD

Comment: te consta que esas peticiones llegan a tu servidor? Porque si el WAF de Cloudflare te dice explícitamente que el bot recibió un challenge, es que está haciendo su trabajo. Si un bot logra saltarse el WAF de Cloudflare que tiene inteligencia artificial, malamente podrá pararlo una herramienta automatizada de bajo nivel. A menos claro que bloquees todas las visitas del planeta, pero no es la idea